# mysql where like and statment isnt working

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I have a search bar on my website and building a page to show parts that have LIKE description and LIKE part name from the keywords in the search.

is_sold will always be an int of 1 or 0.

part_status will always be 1 when approved to be shown on the homepage, search, or category list.

Here is my sql statement

```
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT *
FROM part
WHERE part_name LIKE '%" . $get_search . "%'
  OR part_desc LIKE '%" . $get_search ."%'
  AND is_sold = 0
  AND part_status = 1
ORDER BY id DESC
")
```

It is listing the parts no matter if they are approved and no matter if they are sold or not.

The issue im having is the AND at the end that I set int numbers for 'is_sold' (is part is sold and 'part_status' (if part is approved by administrator).

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I think you need to add parentheses around the appropriate `OR` criteria.

Comment: Thanks @esqew for the tutorial link, currently its on my local host but when I switch over to public I will definitely convert to prepared statements.

Comment: @BrianCherdak: You can't use prepared statements with the deprecated extension. That's the most important thing to address here. You'd better spend some time getting your code to work with `PDO` or `mysqli_*` before you continue writing more code that you're going to have to refactor in the end anyway...

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing `and` and `or` without any `()`, which means MySQL is going to apply its internal operator precedence rules: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html

You probably want:

```
((part_name LIKE x) OR (part_desc LIKE X)) AND (is_sold = 0) AND (part_status = 1)
```

Note the extra brackets around the `or` components.

Comment: Are parenthesis optional or mandatory when using AND statements?

Comment: no. neither. but they ARE mandatory when you're mixing different operators and need them to work in a different ordering than PHP will parse/execute them in. Personally, I ALWAYS put them in. Saves me having to remember the precedence rules for whatever language I'm in, and makes it explicitly clear about the order **I** want them to be executed in.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your combination of `OR` and `AND`:

```
WHERE part_name LIKE '%" . $get_search . "%'
  OR part_desc LIKE '%" . $get_search ."%'
  AND is_sold = 0
  AND part_status = 1
```

Now when the second condition is matched - the `OR` condition - the whole statement evaluates to `true`.

You need something like:

```
WHERE (part_name LIKE '%" . $get_search . "%'
       OR part_desc LIKE '%" . $get_search ."%')
  AND is_sold = 0
  AND part_status = 1
```

Comment: Oh man my mistake on this, so when 2 variables in an OR statements match up they turn into a TRUE inside the parenthesis. Then it goes into an AND. Thank you @jeroen.

Answer (score 2):

You have to structure your condition by parenthesis (), like this

```
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT *
FROM part
WHERE (part_name LIKE ('%" . $get_search . "%')
  OR part_desc LIKE ('%" . $get_search ."%'))
  AND is_sold = 0
  AND part_status = 1
ORDER BY id DESC
");
```

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with esqew (you really should not use mysql_query), try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT *
FROM part
WHERE (part_name LIKE '%" . $get_search . "%'
  OR part_desc LIKE '%" . $get_search ."%')
  AND is_sold = 0
  AND part_status = 1
ORDER BY id DESC
")
```